# Add leading zero to Minutes and Seconds in Javascript countdown timer

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add leading zeros to the minutes and seconds in this javascript countdown timer  i cant get the leadingzero function to work.  that extra leadingzero function i added does not seem to be working:

```
 <pre>  <html>
<head>
</head.
<body>

<p style="font-size:100px;">

<div id="countdown"></div> </p>
<div id="notifier"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

   function display( notifier, str ) {
    document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
  }

 function toMinuteAndSecond( x ) {
   return Math.floor(x/60) + ":" + x%60;
 }



  function setTimer( remain, actions ) {
    (function countdown() {
   display("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));         
   actions[remain] && actions[remain]();
   (remain -= 1) >= 0 && setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
    })();
 }

function leadingzero(setTimer) {

if  (setTimer < 10 && setTimer >=0) 
         return '0' + setTimer;
         else
          return setTimer ; }

{
}

  setTimer(600, {
10: function () { display("notifier", "Just 10 seconds to go"); },
 5: function () { display("notifier", "5 seconds left");        },
 0: function () { display("notifier", "Your access is no longer guaranteed.. you   need    to refresh your page to gain another spot");       }
});   
</script>
</body>
</html>

</pre>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What is the output?

Comment: the code works but, the problem is the output is 9:8  for 9 minutes and 8 seconds  instead of 09:08

Comment: Then, obviously, the statement `return '0' + setTimer;` is never getting executed. I don't even see `leadingzero()` being called at all...

Answer (score 2):

```
function toMinuteAndSecond( x ) {
    mins = Math.floor(x/60)
    secs = x%60
    y = ((mins>0) ? ((mins>9) ? mins : '0'+mins) + ":" : "") 
    y += (secs>9 || mins == 0) ? secs : '0'+secs;
    return y
}
```